# Need an expert advice on *X display manager, window manager and composit manager combination

Tags: linux, window-manager

I have fought with myself whether or not i should ask this question but I find myself stuck and I need another expert opinion. 
I can't seem find the right combination of display and window manager (and composit manager). I have tried so many different combinations but most of them don't work for me. 
I have been working with Linux for a few years now and currently I'm running Gentoo with GDM, Openbox(stand alone, Gnome aware) and xcompmgr. 
 But I have tried Metacity, Awesome and Fluxbox with and without Compiz, but always with GDM. 
What I want: A lightweight, HIGHLY configurable environment that doesn't rely on mouse-input too much (except for web browsing and image processing). At 95% I work with multiple consoles and desktops on multiple screens. 
 What makes me ask is that most lightweight environments seem somewhat "unfinished" and show unexpected behavior quite often. 
And of course I want an environment that's not TOO ugly to look at as I use it at an average of 10 hours a day. :)
Any thoughts? What do you use in a similar situation? Thanks for any advice!

(Please excuse my english as I'm from Germany, btw greetings from Berlin ;)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like XFCE. It fits that description pretty nicely, especially after you configure it's extra window manager options and keyboard shortcuts. IT also supports compositing well.

emerge the following for a good XFCE experience:

```
xfce-base/xfce4-meta 
xfce-extra/xfce4-notifyd
xfce-extra/xfce4-volumed
xfce-extra/thunar-thumbnailers
xfce-extra/xfce4-gvfs-mount
xfce-extra/xfce4-mixer
```

Comment: XFCE, plain and simple

Comment: Thx I will look into it..